# Push notifications for apple in phonegap

Tags: iphone, html, cordova

I am implementing an iphone app using phonegap. I use urban airship for push notifications. The push notifications work well, the only bug is that the title of the notifications is "index.html". Does someone know how to change this default title?

Comment: Try setting your page's title to something. That "index.html" comes from calling a JavaScript alert() function if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just using standard alert(), use the alert function from the [Phonegap API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.1/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification):

```
navigator.notification.alert(message, alertCallback, [title], [buttonName])
```

In your case it would be something like:

```
navigator.notification.alert(theAlertMsgVar, null, 'Your title', null);
```